# Properties of $(m, n) ∈ R \iff m > n$

Tags: relations

Given the following relation, which properties does it fulfill?

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

$(m, n) ∈ R \iff m > n$

***1.) reflexivity***

no, $1 > 1$ (trivially false)

***2.) symmetry***

no, since $x > y\not\rightarrow y > x$, since $2 > 3 \not\rightarrow 3 > 2$

***3.) antisymmetry***

no, since $(2 > 2)\wedge(2>2) \not\rightarrow 2 = 2 $ (trivially false)

***4.) transitivity***

yes, since one can prove that $\forall m,n,r\in R:((m> n ) \wedge (n>r)) \rightarrow m > r$

Comment: Antisymmetry is actually [true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: I had that suspicion. Why is that so? Because actually, you can't find a counter-example, right? But how would one prove that?

Comment: Antisymmetry is incorrect. To show a relation is **not** antisymmetric, you'd need to find $x,y$ such that $x<y$ and $y<x$ but $x \neq y$. Can you find such $x,y$ here?

Comment: Antisymmetry  in this case expresses that if a is larger than b, and b is larger than a, then a = b. Is this true? In your written example, it is trivially true because 2 > 2 is false, and so the implication vacuously holds

Comment: Could I argue that $((x > y) \wedge (y > x))$ is always vacuously false, hence $x = y$ is also vacuously false? This is an implication, where $F$ (false) $\implies F$ (false), hence its truth value is $T$ (true)?

Comment: Related: [The relation "is strictly higher than" is considered antisymmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38830/89922)

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. But, you cannot know that x = y is false from the false premise. However you do get that the premise in the implication is false, which means the implication is true- regardless of if the conclusion is true or false

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Use `\iff` to get $\iff$.